# Storing string with Japanese text and writing to a file

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, file-io

I want to store a Japanese text in a string and write it to a file. I am totally unfamiliar with encoding and there are a lot of data types like wchar_t and wstring in C++ which appear confusing to me. How can I do this?

I am trying to create a well-formed XML file with some CDATA content being Japanese.

Comment: You need to decide what encoding you will use: UTF-16, UTF-32, UTF-8, Shift-JIS, etc. Depending on encoding things will go little different.

Comment: Apparently UTF8 need 3 bites for encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. Use UTF-16 or Unicode

Comment: Where you get the string from and what encoding it is in? Without that information, we can't really give you details on how to do what you need to do.

Comment: @cprogrammer: "Use UTF-16 or Unicode". Unicode is not an encoding; it is a specification that defines _many_ encodings, including UTF-8, UTF-16, and so forth.

Comment: @cprogrammer: There seems to be a misunderstanding about: UTF-8 doesn't need three bytes for encoding; it's a VBR encoding.

Comment: @cprogrammer If the text is mostly ASCII XML with some Japanese strings then UTF-8 only needs 1 byte per ASCII character, the Japanese characters will need 3 bytes. So depending on how much Japanese text is in the file, UTF-8 could be more compact than UTF-16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore the complexities and pitfalls of wide strings altogether; and ensure that the data you are dealing with is encoded using UTF-8 instead.

In C++, UTF-8-strings can be handled just like extended ASCII strings; unless you happen to actually manipulating them (chopping them up, counting characters, things like that).

If all you care about is gathering, storing and displaying the strings, it is quite simply laughably trivial.

(Without more information about the environment in which you are working, it's impossible to tell you exactly *how* you would go about ensuring UTF-8-ness; but that's really beyond the scope of this question.)

**Edit:**

In response to comments regarding what you are planning to do (writing an XML file):

When working with XML *in particular*; it's very, very simple:

**Never Don't Use UTF-8!**, or "N'DUUH!" for short.

In XML, the ASCII-balance will *in practice* **always** be such that UTF-8 is the most space-efficient encoding system.

(To wit, if each Japanese character in the document can be matched by an ASCII character, UTF-8 is exactly as efficient as UTF-16, in terms of space. XML element names are traditionally needlessly verbose, and Japanese sentences are notoriously compact; and when adding in indentation, Japanese text will almost always be matched by ASCII in abundance.)

Comment: Environment: MS Windows, Visual C++ 2008. All I want to do is, to store Japanese text and write it to a file with other English content.

Comment: in my opinion for Japanese it's better to stay to unicode. Using UTF will not save memory since most (all ?) chars will be encoded by a 2 bit value. and it;s harder to parse/manipulate string chars

Comment: @cprogrammer: Normally, that'd be true, but as Guruprasad mentioned in a comment just now; he wants to store it together with other english content in which case UTF-8 will *most likely* be the most memory efficient encoding. UTF-8 is almost always easier to deal with in practice than Unicode, simply because the toolset for dealing with ASCII strings Just Works, and it's a significantly more well-worn and complete toolset. Yes, there are squiggles with text manipulation, but that's not really something you should embark on without a solid understanding of encoding issues, and how text works.

Comment: I guess the solution depends on japanese-english ratio. if most of the text is english and no text manipulation is necessary i'll go for UTF8, otherwise Unicode. An interesting fact that i have fund from Wikipedia is that apparently UTF8 need 3 bites for encoding.

Comment: Hi, I have to create a well-formed XML file with some CDATA content being Japanese.

Comment: @Williham: UTF-8 **is Unicode**. Unicode is not UTF-16, UCS-2, or UTF-32; all of those are valid encodings for Unicode codepoints. They'are all equal parts of Unicode.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Well, no. UTF-8 is not Unicode. It's an encoding of unicode. Only Unicode is Unicode; on account of Unicode being an abstract system for mapping characters to code points. UTF-8 maps code points to sequences of bytes for storage. Due to some confusion about how encoding systems work, however; the term unicode has also come to represent UCS-2; and by further confusion, UTF-16. My previous comment was already 598 characters, so I didn't really have space for a philosophical debate on naming; so instead I chose to use consistent terminology to match what had already been said.

Comment: @cprogrammer: UTF-8 does not need 3 bytes for encoding; it needs 3 bytes to encode (most) Japanese characters. ASCII characters require but one byte, and most "extra" characters in western european languages require two. This is because UTF-8 has a variable bit rate.

Answer (score 0):

`wchar_t` and `std::wstring` can store unicode text, so it's safe to manage and write them to a file.

Be advised that sizeof(wchar_t)==2, and sizeof(char)==1

```
::WriteFile(m_hFile, strString.c_str(), strString.length()*sizeof(wchar_t), pdwWritten, NULL)
```

Comment: Do I need to set the encoding of the file I write the wstring to? It also will contain English text.

Comment: not necessary but it's a god habit, setting encoding will help the reader of the file to figure out how is the content write.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a well-formed XML file with some CDATA content being Japanese.

That's not necessarily a good idea. The `xml:lang` attribute is generally how you tell what language a piece of text contained in XML is in, and you can't apply attributes to CDATA sections. So these should be in some kind of XML element that can have a proper `xml:lang` attribute on it.

In any case, you need to pick an encoding. The entire file must have the same encoding. So make sure to specify your encoding in the XML header. Please don't make XML parsers guess your encoding.

If you're used to writing bytes, I'd suggest UTF-8, as you sidestep a lot of endian issues that you might encounter on other platforms. Each UTF-8 code unit is a `char`, so you can use `std::string` to hold these (though you will have to process them carefully).